# How many ways to select $n$ balls using generating function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, generating-functions, balls-in-bins

Given an infinite number of red, orange and yellow balls. In how many ways can you select $n$ balls if order doesn't matter and the number of red balls must be at least twice as big as the number of orange balls?
This is what I tried so far:

If $x_1$ is the number of red balls, $x_2$ the number of orange balls and $x_3$ the number of yellow balls, then we know:

$$x_1 \geq 2x_2,$$

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = n.$$

From $x_1 \geq 2x_2$ follows $x_1 - 2x_2 \geq 0$, and if we create a new variable $x_4 = x_1 -2x_2$ then we find $x_4 \geq 0$. 
Since $x_4 = x_1 -2x_2$ it follows that $x_1 = x_4 + 2x_2$. Now we find $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = x_4 + 2x_2 + x_2 + x_3 = x_4 + 3x_2 + x_3 = n$ with $x_4 \geq 0$.

For the individual generating functions I found:

$$A_3(x) = A_4(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + ... = \frac{1}{1-x},$$

$$A_2(x) = 1 + x^3 + x^6 + .... = \frac{1}{1-x^3},$$

so for the total generating function I found:

$$A_x(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1-x^3)}.$$

I want to rewrite this to the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ... x^n$, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. (This is particularly relevant when you're mixing fractions and exponents to keep the equations legible.)

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is the number of orange balls
$2a+b$ is the number of red balls
$c$ is the number of yellow balls

We want
$$
3a+b+c=n\tag1
$$
The generating function is
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\ \frac1{1-x^3}\ }^{3a}\overbrace{\ \ \frac1{1-x}\ \ }^{b}\overbrace{\ \ \frac1{1-x}\ \ }^{c}
&=\overbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-1}{k}\left(-x^3\right)^k}^{\frac1{1-x^3}}\overbrace{\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{j}(-x)^j}^{\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{3k}\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)x^j\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) formula, we get the coefficient for $x^n$ to be
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}3\right\rfloor}(n-3k+1)
&=(n+1)\left\lfloor\frac{n+4}3\right\rfloor-\frac32\left\lfloor\frac{n+4}3\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}3\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{n+4}3\right\rfloor\left(n+1-\frac32\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}3\right\rfloor\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{(n+4)(n+1)}6+\frac32\left(\left\{\frac{n+1}3\right\}-\left\{\frac{n+1}3\right\}^2\right)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left\lfloor\frac{(n+2)(n+3)}6\right\rfloor}\tag3
\end{align}
$$